# Angular.js Function not loading in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a directive in angular and I am trying understand why the function link is not loading, if I insert a `console.log('i am working');` before the function link I will able to see the message in my console.

but If I insert a console log inside link function this not load in my page, any Ideas what is happenning? why I cannot get the `console.log` message in my function link?

```
angular.module('components').directive('slider', [
  'jquery',
  function slider($) {
    'use strict';

    var
      scope = {};
console.log('i am working');


    function link($scope, $element) {
      console.log('function link is loading');


          $('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: false,
  infinite: false,
  centerPadding: '2px',
  slidesToShow: 6,
  speed: 200,
  index: 2,

  variableWidth: true,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '40px',
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '40px',
      slidesToShow: 1
    }
  }]
});

}

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: scope,
      templateUrl: 'app/components/slider/slider.html',
      link: link
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: ==> `console.log('function link is loading');` (Or is it just in the question?)

Comment: Are you also missing the closing quote in your code?

Comment: it is just in the question console.log('function link is loading'); i did that but still not loading the function , the strange thing load my first console.log out of the function.

Comment: Show us how you're using the directive in the view

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?  And injecting JQuery is needed?  Typically it just live separately from angular, use you use the included JQLite in the link function.

Comment: And make sure you've included `'components'` in the root module of your app

Comment: components are included, as I said I can get the first console.log message, I just don't get from the one inside link function